# Matlab: Use Splitapply to write multiple files

Tags: matlab, split-apply-combine

**I have grouped tables by a variable and I am trying to write multiple files based on the grouping variable**. But it does not work.

I used `findgroups` and `splitapply`, but the `splitapply` is where I am having problems.

Here is one version of the commands I am using:

```
load patients;
G=findgroups(Gender);
func=@(x,y) csvwrite(x,y);
splitapply(func,Gender,Weight,G);
```

I am getting the following error message:

> Error using splitapply (line 132)
>   Applying the function '@(x,y)csvwrite(x,y)' to the 1st group of data generated the following error:
>
> FILENAME must be a character vector or string scalar.

When I figure out how to use this, I will be using it on large datastore tall arrays. Please help !

Comment: What does not work? Do you get an error message? If so what error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the first parameter of `csvwrite` must be a **file name**.

In your code sample, the first parameter to `csvwrite` is a **cell array**, and not a string.

You can see it by using the following trick:

```
func=@(x,y) display(x);
```

The output of `splitapply(func,Gender,Weight,G)` is:

```
x =

  53×1 cell array

    {'Female'}
    {'Female'}
    {'Female'}
   ...

x =

  47×1 cell array

    {'Male'}
    {'Male'}
    {'Male'}
```

Solution:
Use `x{1}` instead of `x`:

```
func=@(x,y) csvwrite(x{1}, y);
```

It's recommended to add file extension like `.txt` to file name:

```
func=@(x,y) csvwrite([x{1}, '.txt'], y);
```

Remark:
It's possible that the combination of `splitapply` with `csvwrite` misses the original intent of `splitapply` function.
According to documentation it looks like `splitapply` is better fitted for statistical calculations (and not intended to be used for I/O operations [writing files]).
I am not sure whether the above code pattern is the right way for "using it on large datastore tall arrays".

---

Complete code sample:

```
load patients;
G=findgroups(Gender);

%The first parameter of csvwrite must be a file name.
%x{1} = 'Male' for all the Male group, and 'Female' for all the Female group.
%[x{1}, '.txt'] adds a '.txt' extension to the file name.
%
%y will be array of Weight like
%[71
% 69
% 68]
func=@(x,y) csvwrite([x{1}, '.txt'], y);

splitapply(func,Gender,Weight,G)
```